# opencv C++ : How to display webcam capture in windows form application?

Tags: c++, opencv, c++-cli

I use "imwrite" to display BackgroundImage is successful to display image in windows form but it damage to disk:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    namedWindow("video",0);
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    flag = true;
    while(flag){
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        **imwrite("vdo.jpg",frame);**
        this->panel1->BackgroundImage = System::Drawing::Image::FromFile("vdo.jpg");                                         
        waitKey(5);
        delete panel1->BackgroundImage;
        this->panel1->BackgroundImage = nullptr;
    }
}
```

when I'm trying to display without imwrite and use "Bitmap" it wont work here is the source :

```
this->panel1->BackgroundImage = System::Drawing::Bitmap(frame);
```

is there something wrong with my code? thanks for your help :)))

Comment: "it wont work" is not a problem description

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a cv::Mat in a Windows Form application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580397/how-to-display-a-cvmat-in-a-windows-form-application)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because Bitmap's constructor doesn't take **class Mat** as parameter directly.
You should convert the data from **OPENCV Mat** to **.NET Bitmap** by yourself:)

Answer (score 0):

For displaying the image you might need this (another alternative),

```
pictureBox1->Image = gcnew //replacement of cvShowImage

System::Drawing::Bitmap(Img->width, Img->height, Img->widthStep,

System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,(System::IntPtr)Img->imageData);

pictureBox1->Refresh();
```