# How to display a cv::Mat in a Windows Form application?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, video-capture, face-recognition

I tried to use `imwrite` to successfully to display an image on a Windows Form, but it damages the disk, so I need a better way to do this.

Below, is my current code, which writes the image temporarily to the hard drive:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

        namedWindow("video",0);
        VideoCapture cap(0);
        flag = true;
        while(flag){
            Mat frame;
            cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
            **imwrite("vdo.jpg",frame);**
            this->panel1->BackgroundImage = System::Drawing::Image::FromFile("vdo.jpg");

            waitKey(5);
            delete panel1->BackgroundImage;
            this->panel1->BackgroundImage = nullptr;

        }
    }
```

When I try to use the OpenCV `Mat` that is in memory, I cannot get it to work. The following code snippets are what I have tried so far:

```
this->panel1->BackgroundImage = System::Drawing::Bitmap(frame);
```

or

```
this->panel1->BackgroundImage = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap( frame.widht,frame.height,System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Undefined, ( System::IntPtr ) frame.imageData);
```

I want to display `frame` in this code without using `imwrite`. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [opencv C++ : How to display webcam capture in windows form application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579566/opencv-c-how-to-display-webcam-capture-in-windows-form-application)

Comment: Is this c++/cli?

Answer (score 5):

It is definitely a good idea to get away from writing the image to a file and then immediately reading back onto a control. It is quite inefficient as the hard drive is the slowest memory device in the system usually.

I do not believe you are using the correct `Bitmap` constructor in your example above. You should probably be using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14.aspx) constructor definition. Also, telling the `Bitmap` object that the `PixelFormat` is undefined is probably not helping things either. I'm assuming you have a color camera that is returning a `CV_8UC3` matrix (i.e., your `PixelFormat == Format24bppRgb`).

How about try a call like this:

```
this->panel1->BackgroundImage = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(frame.size().width,
                                                              frame.size().height,
                                                              frame.step,
                                                              PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,
                                                              (IntPtr)frame.data);
```

Also, remember that OpenCV natively stores color in BGR format. So, you may need to swap the  red and blue channels to get the data to look right.

Hopefully, that will get you started!

Comment: No problem! If this answer helped solve your problem, mark it as the answer so others who have this problem will know where to look. Thanks! :)

Comment: @mevatron +1 Good advice. Too bad the OP didn't come back to accept it as the official answer. You might be interested in answering [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850492/cvmat-detect-pixelformat) too.