# cv::Mat detect PixelFormat

Tags: c++, opencv, windows-forms-designer, pixelformat

I'm trying to use pictureBox->Image (Windows Forms) to display a cv::Mat image (openCV). I want to do that without saving the Image as a file ('cause i want to reset the image every 100ms). 
I just found that topic here: [How to display a cv::Mat in a Windows Form application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580397/how-to-display-a-cvmat-in-a-windows-form-application)

When i use this solution the image appears to be white only. I guess i took the wrong PixelFormat.
So how do figure out the PixelFormat i need? Haven't seen any Method in cv::Mat to get info about that. Or does this depend on the image Source i use to create this cv::Mat?
Thanks so far :)

Here i took a screen. Its not completely white. So i guess there is some color info. But maybe i'm wrong.
[Screen](http://s7.directupload.net/images/120601/rhl87jf6.png)

Comment: Can you be more specific? What does your code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[cv::Mat.depth()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-depth) returns the pixel type,  eg. CV_8U for 8bit unsigned etc.
and [cv::Mat.channels()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-channels) returns the number of channels, typically 3 for a colour image

For 'regular images' opencv generally uses 8bit BGR colour order which should map directly onto a Windows bitmap or most Windows libs.

SO you probably want system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.Format24bppRgb, I don't know what order ( RGB or BGR) it uses but you can use the opencv cv::cvtColor() with CV_BGR2RGB to convert to RGB

Comment: Thanks so far. 
I tried it like that now
´cv::Mat frame = ocvcamimg->captureCamMatImg(); // Get image
 cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2RGB);
 this->pictureBoxVis->Image = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(frame.size().width,frame.size().height, frame.step,System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,(IntPtr)frame.data);´

But there's still no change. :(

´cv::Mat.depth() == 0 == CV_8U´ and ´cv::Mat.channels() == 3´. So i guess you were right. But what did i do wrong then?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help! The problem was something else.
I just did not allocate memory for the Image Object. So there was nothing to really display.
Using `cv::Mat img;` in the headerFile and `img = new cv::Mat(120,160,0);` in Constructor (ocvcamimg Class) got it to work. (`ocvcamimg->captureCamMatImg()` returns `img`).