# Messages in opencv window

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, winapi

I want to send data to opencv program in order to tell it when to start recording from a camera. I want to send WM_COPYDATA message to a named opencv window and make it handle the message.

I assume `SetWindowsHookEx` with `WH_GETMESSAGE` is the way to go? As far as I looked it requires creating a dll and I'd like to avoid additional files.

Also I found a way to break the loop once 'X' of named window is clicked but before it does break out, it pops out once again after I do click 'X':

```
HWND hwnd = (HWND)cvGetWindowHandle("NamedWindow");
    while (IsWindowVisible(hwnd)) {
    // Functions
}
```

So I think the best way would to be to handle a WM_CLOSE message.

**Edit:**  Ok, I solved it simply by switching from while loop to do-while loop, however, in my opinion, handling a WM_CLOSE message is more appropriate way.

I could create my own window and that would do too but I don't know how to print an image like `cv::imshow("namedwindow", mat)` does.

Comment: You are asking about your proposed solution rather than the problem you are trying to solve. This often leads to an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45944041/edit) your question to ask about what you are trying to accomplish. Vital information includes, which processes are involved (if there is more than one), and which process' code you own.

Comment: "I could create my own window and that would do too" -- do that. HighGUI has a narrow scope of providing simple UI for prototyping of algorithms. You obviously want more. Rather than hacking around those limits, write your own UI that does exactly what you want. Since OpenCV is open source, [you can see exactly how `imshow` works](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/highgui/src/window_w32.cpp) (plus there are questions about this exact topic on SO as well).

Comment: Assuming [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9612765/6544091) code snippet works, I will migrate to c++cli and use windows forms to create a custom window.